# Is there a versioned index of autoconf macros so I know which version to put in AC_PREREQ?

Tags: version, autoconf

I'd like to use `AC_PREREQ` to state the minimum version my `configure.ac` requires. Neither the chapter [Versioning](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Versioning.html) nor the alphabetical index of available macros in the autoconf manual tell me when the specific macros where introduced (at least the chapter on [Obsolete Macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Obsolete-Macros.html) tells me what not to use).

Is there an easier way than comparing old versions of the manual or browsing the changelog to deduce the required version for a macro like `AC_PROG_SED`?

Comment: Even MinGW has autoconf 2.67, so this is not likely to be a problem in practice.

Comment: Is there any reason not to require the version you currently use?  Users of the package do not need to use autoconf.  Developers that will use autoconf to generate the configure script can reasonably be expected to install a modern autoconf.

Comment: I just don't want to enforce a newer autoconf on anybody then really required. But if 2.67 is available everywhere, I'll probably just set that as the minimum version. P.S.: Sorry for the late reply, I expected SO to send me a mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NEWS` file in the source, possibly installed somewhere under `/usr/share/doc/` for you, will tell you.

That said, you probably don't need it.  If all you are worried about is whether a macro exists, `autoconf` will tell you about it when you run it.  (Using `AC_PREREQ` here would be exactly contrary to what Autoconf is all about, namely testing features, not version numbers.)  You could argue that it might save your codevelopers from surprises, but are you really willing to dig up all those version numbers and maintain that carefully?

The case where you might want to test the version is when a macro was changed incompatibly or broken in some version.  But then you probably already know what version that is.

Comment: Indeed, `/usr/share/doc/autoconf/NEWS.gz` has all the info I need. And it looks like 2.67 is a target version which carries most of what one needs nowadays and is available everywhere.